# Apache camel with spring event basic example

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

Using Java and Spring 3.x I am working on example to use apache camel route to produce and consume spring based events. I am surprise google search didn't return any meaningful result. I mean not 1 example using apache camel using spring-event component.

following is my event object/publisher/listener can some one help me convert it using apache camel spring-event:// DSL.

any help is appreciated.

My custom event Class

```
public class CustomSpringEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private String message;

    public CustomSpringEvent(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Publisher

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventPublisher {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public void publishCustomEvent(final String message) {
        System.out.println("Publishing custom event. ");
        CustomSpringEvent customSpringEvent = new CustomSpringEvent(this, message);
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(customSpringEvent);
    }
}
```

Listener

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventListener {
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomSpringEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received spring custom event - " + event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Spring events

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Apache camel spring event component

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/spring-event-component.html

Answer (score 1):

You just create a camel route that starts from `spring-event:foo` where foo can be anything.

Comment: For those (like me) who landed here because their spring event are not making it through their route, make sure your event class extends `org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent`. Other event published through the ApplicationEventPublisher will not show in the route.